# NSTableView add increasing number in row

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I'm trying to make NSTable view app with adding rows with two columns x and y. I want x column to be constant string but y column I want increase the initial number by 1 every time I press button add.

Here is my TableController implementation code

```
@implementation TableViewController

-(id)init {

self = [super init];
if (self) {
    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}

return self;
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
return [list count];
}

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
Number *p = [list objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
return [p valueForKey:identifier];
}

-(IBAction)add:(id)sender{

    [list addObject:[[Number alloc] init]];

    [tableView reloadData];

}

-(void) dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

and Number implementation file:

```
@implementation Number

@synthesize x;
@synthesize y;


-(id) init {
self=[super init];
if (self) {
    int j;
    x = 5;
    y=2+j;
    j++; 
}

return self;
}

@end
```

Number .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int j;
@interface Number : NSObject {
@private 
int x,y;
}

@property int x,y,j;

@end
```

But the number in y column doesn't increase by 1 when I hit the add button. It seems to be reset every time I hit add button. Any help what am I doing wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare j into .h file .

```
.f file:
    int j;
```

int .m file :

```
    -(id) init {
self=[super init];
if (self) {
    x = 5;
    y=2+j;
    j++; 
}

return self;
}
```